# Move generated 0's to the beginning of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I would like to put all the seed [i] values to the right, causing the zeros to be left.
However, if the seed [i] = 0 I want this 0 to be on the right. For example, the value 1056 can be possible because if I chose that seed[i] to be 0.

```js
// Download Function
function download(fileName, text) {
    let element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', fileName);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}
function genBatch (seed) {
    let result = new Array(4);
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        result[i] = seed[i] || "0";
    }
    return result.join("");
}

// Generate File
document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", function(){   
   
    let batch = document.getElementById("batchNumber").value;
    /* /header2 */ 
    let text =  genBatch(batch) + "  ";

    let fileName = document.getElementById("fileName").value + ".txt";
    
    download(fileName, text);
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="container">
          <label for="batchNumber" class="font-weight-bold">Batch Number:</label>
          <input id="batchNumber" type="number" maxlength="4" size="4"/>
          <label for="fileName" class="font-weight-bold">File Name:</label>
          <input id="fileName" type="text"/>
    </div>  
    <button id="generate" type="button" class="btn btn-light font-weight-bold mx-auto">Generate File</button>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify and potentially give more input / output values you are thinking of? Currently I find your requirements very confusing at best :)

Comment: The batch number only accepts 4 numbers. if I put the value 4 in the input, it generates a file with the number 4000. What I look for is when I put the number 4 in the input the generated file has 0004 as a value and not 4000. if you put 40 the number in the generated file needs to be 0040.

Comment: Are you just looking for `const genBatch = (n) => ('0000' + n).slice(-4)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.toLocaleString()` with the `minimumIntegerDigits` option.

```js
const padZ = (num, min) => num.toLocaleString('en-US',{
  minimumIntegerDigits:min,useGrouping:false
});

console.log(padZ(4,4))
console.log(padZ(40,4))
console.log(padZ(400,4))
console.log(padZ(4000,4))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just looking for the `padStart` method.

[String​.prototype​.pad​Start() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

```js
const getAsString = (num, minLen) => {
  return (num||'').toString().padStart( minLen||4, '0'); 
};

console.log(getAsString());
console.log(getAsString(1));
console.log(getAsString(333));
console.log(getAsString(1234));
```